# Как изменять несколько селектов одновременно

Tags: javascript, select

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении значени в селекте1 это же значение переключалось в селекте2 и наоборот

https://jsfiddle.net/k46wnpqz/2/

```js
   $(".select").on('change', function(){
      switch ($(".select").val()) {
        case "1 kom = 55 BAM":
          $(".item-gift").text("1 kom = 55 BAM")
          break;
        case "2 kom = 75 BAM":
          $(".item-gift").text("2 kom = 75 BAM")
          break;
        case "3 kom = 90 BAM":
          $(".item-gift").text("3 kom = 90 BAM")
          break;
        case "4 kom = 110 BAM":
          $(".item-gift").text("4 kom = 110 BAM")
          break;
        case "6 kom = 150 BAM":
          $(".item-gift").text("6 kom = 150 BAM")
          break;
        default:
          $(".item-gift").text("1 kom = 55 BAM")
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_container">
  <select class="input__inner select" id="priceListId1" name="amount">
    <option selected>1 kom = 55 BAM</option>
    <option>2 kom = 75 BAM</option>
    <option>3 kom = 90 BAM</option>
    <option>4 kom = 110 BAM</option>
    <option>6 kom = 150 BAM</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="item-gift">1 kom = 55 BAM</div>

<div class="form_container">
  <select class="input__inner select" id="priceListId1" name="amount">
    <option selected>1 kom = 55 BAM</option>
    <option>2 kom = 75 BAM</option>
    <option>3 kom = 90 BAM</option>
    <option>4 kom = 110 BAM</option>
    <option>6 kom = 150 BAM</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="item-gift">1 kom = 55 BAM</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении значени в селекте1 это же
> значение переключалось в селекте2 и наоборот

```js
const selects = $('select.select');
selects.change(function() {
  const val = $(this).val();
  selects.each(function() {
    $(this).val(val);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_container">
  <select class="input__inner select">
    <option selected>1 kom = 55 BAM</option>
    <option>2 kom = 75 BAM</option>
    <option>3 kom = 90 BAM</option>
    <option>4 kom = 110 BAM</option>
    <option>6 kom = 150 BAM</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form_container">
  <select class="input__inner select">
    <option selected>1 kom = 55 BAM</option>
    <option>2 kom = 75 BAM</option>
    <option>3 kom = 90 BAM</option>
    <option>4 kom = 110 BAM</option>
    <option>6 kom = 150 BAM</option>
  </select>
</div>
```